# Web Scrapping - empty list

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrap data from the below ecommerce site. But I am getting blank list while trying to append names in the Brand_Names list. Below is my code for the same. I am performing this task using selenium. I have not mentioned code for importing the required libraries. Rest code is pasted below

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(2)
url='https://www.amazon.in/'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
driver.maximize_window()
#Searching element for search field   
search_field=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="nav-search-field "]/input')

user_inp=input("Enter your search value: ")

search_field.send_keys(user_inp)
time.sleep(2)

search_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="nav-search-submit nav-sprite"]')

search_btn.click()

URLs=[]

for page in range(0,3):
    links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2"]//a')
    for i in links:
        URLs.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
    nxt_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="s-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator"]')
    nxt_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)

Brand_Name=[]
Product_Name=[]
Price=[]
Expected_Delivery=[]

for i in URLs:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        brands=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="bylineInfo"]')
        Brand_Name.append(brands.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Brand_Name.append('-')
```

Comment: The code in the question does not work: for example it is missing the imports for `webdriver` and `time`.
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The middle part of your code is where the bugs lie:

```py
URLs=[]

time.sleep(2)

for page in range(0,3):
    URL = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style a-text-normal']")]
    URLs.extend(URL)
    nxt_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="s-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator"]')
    nxt_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)

Brand_Name=[]
Product_Name=[]
Price=[]
Expected_Delivery=[]

for i in URLs:
    driver.get(i)
```

I've fixed the 1st loop so the URLs are fetched properly. Remember to import the relevant libraries, e.g., `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`. The 2nd loop begins with a bug, but the rest of your code seems fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Out of curiosity is there any way I can correct my existing code.

Comment: Just replace the part from `URLs = []` to `driver.get(i)` with my part, import the missing libraries, then let me know what error it's throwing up again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Duc, it worked now. I just replaced driver.get(url) with driver.get(i)